# React-intl const <FormattedMessage /> is giving [object object] as result

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using `"react-intl": "^2.4.0"`, and `"react": "^16.2.0"`.

I am trying to assign the output of `<FormattedMessage/>` tag to a constant and put it in the input tag placeholder.

[image: Code Image]

Expected Output Input field with text in the respective language in it but it is coming [object object] inside the text box.

Comment: Why do you want to assign an object in placeholder of input tag? It should be <input placeholder="Enter something" /> but not assigning an object

Comment: Instead of image put code

Comment: `<FormattedMessage />` will return object not string and `placeholder` expects String

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`<FormattedMessage />` is a component which cannot be placed to `placeholder` which expects a raw String.

```
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl'; 

class TestComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const { intl } = this.props;
    return (
        <input placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "loginPage.username", defaultMessage: 'username'})}/>
    )
  }
}

export default injectIntl(TestComponent);
```

Comment: better said that `<FormattedMessage />` is a component which just cannot be placed to `placeholder` which expects a raw string.

Comment: Getting this error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined"
Then i use  
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl, formatMessage } from "react-intl";
Error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined"

Comment: You have to get `intl` from `formatMessage` and once you will wrap your class from `injectIntl` you will be able to see `formatMessage` in props.