# add React-intl to placeholder IN OBJECT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with `const inputProps`. I try add a React-intl to react-autosuggest placeholder input, but now, this placeholder is: `[Object object]`.

```
getStepContent = (step) => {    
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: <FormattedMessage {...messages.inputAccountNumber} />, // <--
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange,
      maxLength: 26,
    };

...

    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Autosuggest
              inputProps={inputProps} // <--
            />
          </Fragment>
        );
...
```

Comment: could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423291/react-intl-cosnt-formattedmessage-is-giving-object-object-as-result

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is a string, you putted an Object in it.
You can write the code like this:

```
import intl from 'react-intl-universal'
...
placeholder: intl.get(messages.inputAccountNumber).d(messages.inputAccountNumber), // <--
```